# Cordova Google Analytics plugin working locally but not when installed from Play Store

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-analytics, cordova-plugins

My events show up perfectly in Google Analytics when I use `cordova run android` with my device connected via USB. But when I install the same code on the same device (or other devices) from the Play Store, I get no events or page loads whatsoever.

I'm only working with Android right now (obviously). My config.xml was already set to `<access origin="*" />`, but when it didn't work I added these for (redundant?) good measure:

`<access origin="http://*.google-analytics.com"/>
<access origin="https://*.google-analytics.com"/>`

It didn't work with either of these states. Any idea why this might be happening?

Installed plugins:

`cc.fovea.cordova.purchase 4.0.0 "Purchase"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.0 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.0 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 3.0.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-google-analytics 0.8.1 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.0.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.0.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.0 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.0.7 "SocialSharing"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.3.1 "Toast"`

config.xml: http://pastebin.com/mRH2jaET

Cordova version 5.4.1

Just to clarify in case there's any ambiguity:

- Everything else about my app works fine. All the other plugins work as expected, and the Google Analytics plugin works as expected when I install it locally.
- I've got CSP set up in my .html files and I don't have any CSP-related errors.

Comment: Are you using the SDK with and IDE (Android Studio, Visual Studio, Eclipse, etc)? If so, please add that to your post. If not, you've got a big problem, and it would be best to abandon this post.

Comment: I'm not using an IDE, but I've developed cordova apps successfully without one before. Can you elaborate on why that means I ought to abandon this post?

Comment: Yes. I will in my answer. Which will take about 20minutes to write.

Answer (score 0):

@Sarah,

after review of your `config.xml` it is apparent you are new to Cordova/Phonegap. You are using a mix of XML components without real knowledge as to how what the mean and how they are used.

0) *Phonegap Build* is a cloud-based build service run by Phonegap/Adobe.

1) You have NOT use the *Phonegap Build* tag in your Stackoverflow post. This conflicts with your post and your `config.xml`.

2) You are using the `gap:` prefix on some of your XML components. This prefix is intended ONLY for *Phonegap Build*, a cloud-based service by Phonegap/Adobe.

3) You are also using `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`.

This component is intended for adding XML components to the final `AndroidManifest.xml`, but this is only for *Phonegap Build*. To my knowledge this is not supported by any other tools sets.

4) This appears to be in support of #3.

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
     <application android:debuggable="false" />
</gap:config-file>
```

However, `android:debuggable="false"` does NOT need to used, as all frameworks that use Cordova have a *debug* and *release* switch. This chunk of code has not been needed for over two (2) years. It is seen on some older blogs, but blogs are outdated. NOTE: any blog over 6 months old (as of today 2015-12-28) has the potentional to be outdated and wrong.

5) `<feature (...) />` is ONLY used with the SDK. This is to support IDEs, hence my orignal question.

See Documentation -> [The `config.xml` File](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/config_ref/index.html) -> The *feature* Element

**I Quote**

> If you use the CLI to build applications, you use the plugin command to enable device APIs. This does **not* modify the top-level config.xml file, so the `<feature>` element does not apply to your workflow.
>
> **If you work directly in an SDK and using the platform-specific config.xml file as source, you use the `<feature>` tag to enable device-level APIs and external plugins.** They often appear with custom values in platform-specific config.xml files.

6) Again, you are using the `gap:` prefix, but in this case you are using it with plugins. You are using outdated names and your are not listing the [new *source=npm*](http://phonegap.com/blog/phonegap-build/)

But again, you did not use the *Phonegap Build* tag. This leads me to believe you are using a boilerplate, but you are likely using the wrong boilerplate. This is because Cordova/Phonegap has 3 platforms. Read [#1](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) of [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

7) You are using `<engine name="android" spec="~4.1.1" />`. This and the `whitelist` entries tell me this is a fairly recent boiler plate. The latest version of [Cordova Android is pinned to 4.1.1](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/11/24/tools-release.html). See also [Platforms and Plugins Version Management](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/platform_plugin_versioning_ref/index.html) -> Saving Platforms

8) You will need to use the `whitelist` plugin and depending on how your code it written you'll need to use `CSP`.

**In summary**, you have components of *Phonegap Build*, *Phonegap SDK*, but your post indicates you are using *Phonegap CLI*. You will need to unscramble the mess you have before you can proceed.

Lastly, you cannot be installing from *Play Store*, because if you got *"from the Play Store, I get no events or page loads whatsoever."* as you say – you would never be in the store to begin with.

I strongly recommend you start over and do ONE (1) plugin at at time, else you will drive yourself crazy. And for that matter, at this point in time the best I can do, is point you to restart your work. As such, here is some reading: [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md) – Best of Luck

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer! I've been struggling to figure out what parts of my config.xml are relevant and which aren't, and it's mostly been fruitless. I'll go through this line by line and try to internalize each item you're describing.

I am confused by this, however: "Lastly, you cannot be installing from Play Store ... as you say – you would never be in the store to begin with." My app *is* on the store (and working fine in in my beta testers' devices), but it's just not logging events. Maybe I'm misunderstanding you?

Comment: Oops, I guess I can't edit my comment anymore, so I'll post another: FYI, I did add each plugin one at a time, and successfully, before moving on to the next. They're all working fine, though I certainly believe that my config.xml is a mess and needs to be straightened out!

Comment: On the issue of *Play Store*, if your app was \*not\* functional, as you claim, it would not be allowed in the store. As such, your description is in conflict - which makes it very difficult to give you a concrete answer. You'll need to clear up your description when posting. NOTE: I am not calling you a liar - just inconsistent in your description. This may be because you see it one way in your mind, but write it incompletely in your description &ndash; without really realizing it.

Comment: You have 5 minutes to add to old comments.

Comment: My app is completely functional, but no Google Analytics events or page loads are logged. (I don't think this was inconsistent with my original question, but it's not worth belaboring the point further.) In any case, I'm very happy to have had your thorough commentary on my config, and if my clarification in this comment changes your recommendation, I'd be eager to hear any additional thoughts you may feel like sharing.

Comment: Apparently, I have not been clear enough. Fix your `config.xml` and your App (except for the Google Analytics, of course), and start another post, and I will help you. If I attempt to help you with your goal (Google Analytics), it will break other things. You can also take a chance on a new post, or someone else answering this question for you.